# Open a popup window and focus on it

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to open a popup window and focus on it but my efforts are in vain.
Occasionally, the popup goes behind the main window. My desktop is shared by two screens and I am using Internet Explorer 8.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
window.open(url,'_blank').focus();
```

Comment: Can u try it with setTimeout: `var w=window.open(url,'_blank'); setTimeout(function(){w.focus()},10);`

Comment: ... or alternatively put `window.focus()` in a `window.onload` event handler in the pop-up. Though this can be done only, if you have control over `url` source file.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: But my `window.open` returns `null` for some reason even if the window is opened behind, tried to investigate about that but didn't find any clue.

Comment: @User49234123412341 in every browser or just IE? About IE check http://stackoverflow.com/a/7025648/961695

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's just in IE but apparently I can't notify to each and every user to disable protected mode.