# focus function not working in ie8

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I have a button click and in it i put a javascript function to open a new window and if i again click the button the same window refresh again and point to it.Working both in firefox and chrome.but not in IE.Here is the code i tried

```
<button onclick="popitup('http://www.google.com');">click</button>

 var newwindow = null;
    function popitup(url) {
        if ((newwindow == null) || (newwindow.closed)) {
            newwindow = window.open(url, 'Buy', 'width=950,height=650,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
            newwindow.focus();
        } else {
            newwindow.location.href = url;
            newwindow.focus();
        }
    }
```

IE return newwindow==null all the time...that is the issue...any solution?

Comment: How does this use C#, exactly?

Comment: default button behavior is `submit`, so try set `type='button'`

Comment: Check that IE does not block popup windows, also possibly duplicate [On IE9, Win 7 window.open() returns null instead of reference of the opened window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014242/on-ie9-win-7-window-open-returns-null-instead-of-reference-of-the-opened-wind)

Comment: @Grundy ..IE return newwindow==null all the time...that is the issue...any solution?

Comment: @AnilkumarM do you check that IE does not block popups? are you going by link?

Answer (score 0):

It's Works for me

```
function windowOpen(url) {
win = window.open(url, 'OpenPage', 'resizable=yes,width=900px,height=620px');
win.focus();

return false;

}
```

If not please check for your current window name is same as newwindow if yes plaese use another name insted of newwindow

Comment: do you check your IE does not block popups?

Comment: @Grundy sorry bro, but he didn't answered to you. that's why i asked the same

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that:

http://hardlikesoftware.com/projects/IE8FocusTest.html

Hope it helps..

Comment: IE return newwindow==null all the time...thts the issue...any solution?

Comment: sorry wrong link. have u seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326993/jquery-focus-sometimes-not-working-in-ie8