# IE11-facing issue while calling focus() on window object

Tags: javascript, window, internet-explorer-11

Trying to run a following simple code on IE11 browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Popup Example</title>
  <script>
function ButtonClick2() {
var thewin = window.open("http://www.google.com",'thewin','width=400, height=420,status=no');            
window.thewin.focus();

        }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
   <button onclick="ButtonClick2()">Click Me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

ISSUE:On IE11 it gives the error statement "**Unable to get property 'focus' of undefined or null reference"**

Comment: Seems to work at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2J6X/). Have you pop-up blocker on in IE?

Comment: No, It work fine with IE8 but it gives issue with IE11.

Answer (score 3):

This answer's late, but I thought that I'd post it just in case somebody came across this question in the future.

According to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7025648/1600090,
and my own experience, one possible cause could be that you're trying to open a window in a different internet zone for which Protected Mode is enabled.  By default, IE11 enables Protected Mode for the Internet and Restricted zones but disables it for Local Intranet and Trusted Sites.  So, for example, if your page (and/or site) are running in your Local Intranet zone and you're trying to open a new window in the Internet zone, window.open is going to return a null reference.  If the page/site which is launching the new window is in the Internet zone, in my experience, window.open will return a reference.  So, @ssut's example in jsfiddle is going to work because jsfiddle.com and google.com are probably both in the same zone (I'm assuming the Internet zone).

Comment: Thanks for posting this. So helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Please check the variable scope. This issue is not browser's problem.

In your code, `var thewin = window.open(..` in the `ButtonClick2` function, but `window.thewin.focus();` is point to `window` object's `thewin` variable.

Change the code to `thewin.focus();` then it works perfectly.

New code:

```
PE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Popup Example</title>
  <script>
function ButtonClick2() {
var thewin = window.open("http://www.google.com",'thewin','width=400, height=420,status=no');            
thewin.focus();

        }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
   <button onclick="ButtonClick2()">Click Me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have u tried above code on IE11 browser?Because for me its still not woking on IE11 browser.same error..:(

Comment: @JITSU83 yes. it works without any errors. screenshot: http://puu.sh/a0Mtg/78ff4aed48.png jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eM26M/