# javascript window.focus() giving error oin MS Edge when opening internet link

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am using window.open() to open a new window and when i use window.focus(), it gives error "Unable to get property focus of undefined or null reference", when using MS Edge

I checked this question and it fixed the issue for IE:
[IE11-facing issue while calling focus() on window object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605426/ie11-facing-issue-while-calling-focus-on-window-object)

But this issue is still occuring on **MS Edge**. So this should not be a duplicate.

I am able to open intranet sites without any error, but when i open any external site in the popup, it gives this popup.

I saw this link on msdn which states that the Enhanced protected mode runs all the time in MS Edge. Could this be a  reason for the issue?

i have already dcisable the Protected mode and Enhanced protected mode in Internet Options.

Please suggest ??

Folowing is my javascript function:

```
function LaunchCenteredWindowWithBars(windowWidth, windowHeight, windowName, windowUri) {
    try {
        var centerWidth = (window.screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
        var centerHeight = (window.screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;

        newWindow = window.open(windowUri, windowName, 'width=' + windowWidth +
                ',height=' + windowHeight +
                ',left=' + centerWidth +
                ',top=' + centerHeight +
                ',toolbar=1,location=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes');

        newWindow.focus();
    }
    catch (e) { alert(e.message); }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add the msdn link:

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/11/microsoft-edge-building-a-safer-browser/

Comment: Try adding "var" in front of "newWindow". Also check if newWindow is not null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question may be in this other posting...

[focus() is not working in edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948486/focus-is-not-working-in-edge-browser/44560690#44560690)